# python module installed but not opening in IDLE 3.8

Tags: python-3.x

so, I installed a python module using `pip install` using the administrator mode by cmd prompt. When I tried to import it in a program in IDLE 3.8 it gives the error "module not found". What could be the reason behind this and what's the solution?

Comment: Try `python3 -m pip install <>`

Comment: `pip install` only gets the base python packages. to get extra packages look them up on https://pypi.org/ and use the `pip import <package name>` as stated on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use pip3 for python3. Does that solve your problem? Or your IDLE uses a different interpreter or virtual environment than the one in which you have installed your modules.